# How to set google calendar widget as trasparent in kitkat?

Tags: nexus-4, google-calendar

My nexus 4 is updated to the last version of google calendar.

Now I am not able to set the trasparency option.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a  other calernder client (app). For example [Business Calendar (Kalender)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=netgenius.bizcal&hl=de&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dbusiness%20calendar&pcampaignid=APPU_PQBrVIPdO-X6ygPs2IHwCQ)

This has transparent widgets. You only have to connect this app with your Google account then will sync the widget it with your Google cal. app